# Angular proxy + corporate proxy

Tags: angular, proxy

I have Angular project with next proxy:

```
const PROXY_CONFIG = {
  "/teploset": {
    "target": "http://95.1.0.3:8080/",
    "secure": false,
    "bypass": function (req, res, proxyOptions) {

      console.log("1");


    },
    "changeOrigin": true
  }
}

module.exports = PROXY_CONFIG;
```

I need proxy because of CORS issue when requests go to back-end.
Everything works good at home, but problems are at work where we use corporate proxy.
So I get next error:

> [HPM] Error occurred while trying to proxy request /teploset/login
>   from localhost:4200 (ENETUNREACH)

Any ideas?